# Unexpected data found. \r\n while trying to submit date in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

In m Laravel-5.8, I am trying to used JQuery datepicker for my date:

Request Rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'holiday_name' => [
            'required', 
            'min:3',
            'max:80',
                Rule::unique('hr_holiday_dates')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('group_id', $this->group_id)
                        ->where('holiday_name', $this->holiday_name)
                        ->where('holiday_date', Carbon::parse($this->holiday_date)->format('d-m-Y'));
                })               
        ],            
        'group_id' => [
            'required'              
        ], 
        'holiday_date' => [
            'required', 
            'date',
            'date_format:d-m-Y',
        ],                                

    ];
}
```

`config/app.php`

```php
'date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
'date_format_js' => 'dd/mm/yy',
```

Model

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HrHolidayDate extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_holiday_dates';

    protected $fillable = [
        'holiday_name',
        'holiday_date',

    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'holiday_date'
    ];


    protected $casts = [];


    public function setHolidayDateAttribute($input)
    {
        $this->attributes['holiday_date'] =
            Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
    }


    public function getHolidayDateAttribute($input)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input)
            ->format(config('app.date_format'));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(StoreHolidayDateRequest $request)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('holiday_date_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }  

try {
    $holidayDate    = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->holiday_date)->format('d-m-Y');
    $holiday        = HrHolidayDate::create([
        'holiday_name'      => $request->holiday_name,
        'holiday_date'      => $holidayDate,
    ]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Holiday is created successfully');
    return redirect()->route('hr.holiday_dates.index');
    
   } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return redirect()->route('hr.holiday_dates.index');
    }        
}
```

And here is my view blade:

view

```
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Holiday:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input  type="text" name="holiday_name" placeholder="Enter holiday here" class="form-control" value="{{old('holiday_name')}}">
            </div>
          </div>       
            
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Holiday Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                </div>                        
                    <input type="text" class="form-control holiday_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="holiday_date" value="{{old('holiday_date')}}" >
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>                                         

    <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="submit_create" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

    </div>   

<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $( '.holiday_date' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,     
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                duration: 'fast',                    
                yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
            });
    });
</script>
```

When I submitted, I got this error:

> Unexpected data found. \r\n

> #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php"

How do I resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: May be you need to change js `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'` to `dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'`

Comment: @STA - Nothing changed. The problem is still there